# NaN in Logit When using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I applied DenseNet in Tensorflow to do a simple binary classification task and finetuned the last few layers. To avoid the NaN issue in back-prop, I have already decreased the learning rate to 1e-7.

Yet, I still got NaN in **Logit** summary. But how could logit be NaN due to it's just a feed forward operation of model.

By the way, because the DenseNet is converted from PyTorch pretrained model, I usd same preprocess method and got inputs with min -2.1, max 2.6, mean -0.3. and std 1.3. Besides, I change the last FC layer to my own with 0.01 regularization scale.

Currently, I have two hypotheses. The first one is the std in BN got an zero value. The second one is that the model got a weird input.

Yesterday, through printing logs of each layers' outputs and variables, I found the reason is that the gradient explosion caused some variables being updated to NaN. Because the error occurs in logit summary, it mislead me to think problem is in feed-forward. Now, by using **gradient clipping** tricks, I addressed this issue.

Comment: What kind of activation function are you using?
And NaN can still occur in feed-forward operation, if the values being calculated becomes too large or infinitesimally small (more probable). 
Check if all the input values are fine. Especially look that you don't have any NaN values in your input.

As per your hypothesis, batch-normalization generally has an epsilon added to batch-variance in the denominator to avoid these cases. And since variance can never be negative, we can assume this value to be always higher than the epsilon value. Also, try using higher epsilon to see if it helps.

Comment: The activation is ReLu. I kind of think PyTorch giving a misleading docs about DenseNet preprocessing. I tried another TensorFlow DenseNet repo with pretrained model,  the preprocessing is quite different. I will try to confirm this today.